# How to avoid I/O error 32 when handling file being used by software

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7

I have a scientific instrument with some software that leaves something to be desired... but it's proprietary and I can't do anything about changing how the software works. So I'm trying to play nice with it.

**Here's my setup:**

The software creates a text file to store the data. With every new observation (every 10 seconds) it appends the latest observation to the text file. I want to save the file to a shared network drive so I can have instant up-to-date access of the file on my other computer. However, if the laptop loses connection to the network drive for even a small amount of time while the software tries to write to the file, the software breaks and all observations after that are lost into cyberspace. I get I/O Error 103.

So here's a little batch file I've written up to save the data locally on the hard drive first and then make copies periodically:

```
set /p name= File name (without ".txt"):
set source= C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\%name%.txt
set destination= Z:\SKQ201701S\Birk_data\O2\%name%.txt

:loop
copy %source% %destination%
timeout /t 10
goto loop
```

**Here's my problem:**

Sometimes I get I/O error 32. From what I've read, this is due to multiple programs trying to access the same file at the same time. So I'm assuming that sometimes the software tries to append a new observation to the file while my batch script is copying the file. When that happens, I get the error message. I've read about files being locked when they're accessed, but maybe this software doesn't lock the file while writing? I'm not sure...

How can I avoid this happening? All the answers I've found so far assume that both of the processes are under the user's control. Typically in the same batch script. But in my case I can't control the proprietary software.

I'm on Windows 7. Any ideas?

Comment: This is caused because the software **is** locking the file while writing, preventing your batch file from opening it. There are two solutions, neither of which I suspect will work for you: 1) stop the software during your copy operation and restart it after, or 2) contact the software vendor and ask them to change the way it writes to the file.

Comment: I take it with a line appending every 10 seconds, the file grows pretty large.  That probably rules out a cloud auto sync solution.  Would an acceptable alternative be to [`tail -n 300`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) the file to get the most recent observations for the past 5 minutes?  That would let you make a reasonably fast copy of summary data without having to copy a 200 gig file every 10 seconds.  And if the copy to the net share fails, it would be less likely to affect your instrument monitoring software.

Comment: Can be done, but it isn't trivial.  The key is [opportunistic locking](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130415-00/?p=4663).  You would have to write a program to read the file contents while holding an opportunistic lock.  (I'm not sure about the race condition mentioned in the comments, though.  I think the failure rate might be low enough to be acceptable, e.g., once in a hundred years.)

Comment: ... note that I'm assuming it is the proprietary program that is failing with error 32.  If it is your batch file, you shouldn't need to worry about it, since you'll be trying again in a few seconds anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set /p name= File name (without ".txt"):
set source= C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\%name%.txt
set destination= Z:\SKQ201701S\Birk_data\O2\%name%.txt

:loop
FOR %%a IN (%source%) DO SET fsize=%%~za
:: wait until size of actual file increases
:monitor
timeout /t 1
FOR %%a IN (%source%) DO IF %fsize% geq %%~za GOTO monitor
:: a little time to stabilise
timeout /t 1
copy %source% %destination%
goto loop
```

Since the critical point is when the software appends to the file, then the filsize will increase, so simply wait for a filesize-increase and do the copy then, since the next increase isn't due for 10 sec...

Comment: Great idea! Thanks Magoo!

Comment: Oh shoot. I jumped the gun here. Sorry. I'm still getting the error. Your answer makes sense though. Why would there still be an error???

Comment: Ah well. Might have worked. What's obvious is that the application is trying to reopen the file before the batch/copy operation is complete. So - perhaps you could *rename* the file by adding a sequence number, then append the renamed file to the destination file. You'd end up with a huge number of tiny files that way... Perhaps you could set the file up on a ramdrive, then copy the file to another name on the ramdrive and *then* on to the network. That should minimise the amount of time that the batch has posession of the file that is in dispute.